# Calling same method before typical events in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In Selenium Webdriver, I have to call a particular method before every "click / submit" event of every method wherever these events appear in a class. I can simply do that by invoking same method (to be repeated) before each click/ submit event. But consider if there are total 100 click events in a class. It would be cumbersome. Instead I have to give some logic and condition so that I call a method at one place with condition provided for click/submit events and subsequently it is applied before all such events.

How can I achieve this?

Note: Statements of Click/Submit event could be different.

Answer (score 0):

Create a parameter customized Click/Submit method (which may accept the locator on which you want to perform the action) with the method you want to call before click/submit  And use that customized method in your test code.

It will be onetime task.

Comment: Hi Arun, can you please elaborate on this with example code in brief. It would be a great help!

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a wrapper class (and derive the test class from it) or use a static method. In Java it would look like this:

```
   void extendedClick(WebElement webElement) {
        System.out.printf("Clicking on %1$s", webElement.toString());
        webElement.click();
    }
```

The system out is where you can place your additional method. The test class can either call

```
//normal click 
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(element));
webElement.click();
```

or

```
//extended click 
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(element));
extendedClick(webElement);
```

If you don't want to use a wrapper class, you can place `extendedClick` in a static context and invoke it accordingly. In order to meet the second part of your requirement

> I have to give some logic and condition so that I call a method at
>   one place with condition provided for click/submit events and
>   subsequently it is applied before all such events.

here is an example with static context in which the condition (which may be determined at runtime) is provided by the caller:

```
public class TestcaseHelper {
    private static boolean useExtension = false;

    /*** @param webElement element on which to perform click
     *   @param condition if true, extended click will be performed for this and any subsequent invocations
     */
    public static void extendedClick(WebElement webElement, boolean condition) {
        if (useExtension || condition) {
            useExtension = true;
            System.out.printf("Clicking on %1$s", webElement.toString());
        }
        webElement.click();
    }

    /** Reset extended click */
    public static void resetCondition() {
        useExtension = false;
    }
}
```

Test case:

```
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(element));
TestcaseHelper.extendedClick(webElement, this.determineIfConditionIsTrue());
```

Answer (score 0):

Or in C#, you could also choose to use an ExtensionMethod:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void ExtendedClick(this IWebElement element)
    {
        DoFancyStuff();

        element.Click();
    }
}
```

Note the `this` keyword, which actually makes your static method an extension method of IWebElement. Then, instead of calling

```
DoFancyStuff();
driver.FindElement(...).Click();
```

over and over again, you can simply call

```
driver.FindElement(...).ExtendedClick();
```